# Why does the carry flag not set?

Tags: assembly, x86

Can someone explain why the carry flag does not set when I call `inc al` in the following code:

```
mov al,ff 
inc al
int 3
```

[image]

As far as I understand it moving the hex value ff(255) to the 8-bit register and then incrementing it by one would cause the carry flag to be set because it goes over the maximum value the register can hold. But when I run the code the value in the al register goes back to zero and the carry flag is not set. Can someone explain this better to me?

Comment: `inc` always leaves CF unmodified.  It's not the same as `add al,1`  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/inc#aflags-affected

Comment: Oh thank you so much! I did not know this!